# News site in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, performance

I am new to ASP.NET Core 3.1 with no background of MVC. I am just moving from Web Forms to ASP.NET Core. I asked elsewhere and I got the following comments regarding my code. The code is working fine for me, but I am not sure how to improve it with the provided feedback.

I want to know how can I clean this code and write more optimized code based on the below code. I would appreciate examples with code.

> it's actually a bit buggy. There's no need to explicitly open or close
> the connection (Dapper will open it), and using will dispose the
> connection even in cases where finally won't execute.
>
> Another bug - catch(Exception ex){throw ex;} throws a new exception
> with a different stack trace. It's worse than no catch at all. To
> rethrow the original exception after eg logging, use throw;, without
> an exception object

**Editor note**: the quote says "buggy" or "bug", but the things cited are not actually *bugs*. They are suggestions to remove redundant code, or to change minutiae side-effects of exception semantics.

`NewsController.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookListRazor.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using BookListRazor.Data;

namespace BookListRazor.Controllers
{
    // [Route("api/News")]
     //[Route("api/News/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NewsController : Controller
    {
        //for EF
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        //For  Dapper
        private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;


        public NewsController(ApplicationDbContext db, SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _db = db;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        
        //get all news 
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/news/GetAll")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {

            //fetch data using EF
            // return Json(new { data = await _db.News.OrderByDescending(x => x.NewsDate).ToListAsync() });

            //Fetch data using Dapper
            IEnumerable<News> newslist;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
            {
                string query = "select * FROM News";

                conn.Open();
                try
                {
                    newslist = await conn.QueryAsync<News>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
            return Json(new { data = newslist });
        } 
        
    }
}
```

and in the razor/cshtml:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
     $.ajax({
                url: "api/news/getallnews/1",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var len = response.data.length;
                    var table = $("<table><tr><th>Details</th></tr>");
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        //console.log("i "+i);
                        table.append("<tr><td>Title:</td><td>" + response.data[i].newsHeading + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                    table.append("</table>");
                    $("#news").html(table);
                }
            });

    });
</script>
```

and:

```
//get all news 
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/news/GetAllData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllData()
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        //  param.Add("@prodtype", prodtype);
        //return connection.QueryFirst(" select * FROM News");
        string query = "select * FROM News";
        IEnumerable<News> newslist;
        newslist = await connection.QueryAsync<News>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
        return Json(new { data = newslist });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `GetAll`, the feedback you've already had seems pretty valid, to be honest; there is really no value in re-throwing an exception you've caught *directly*; if this is after some kind of processing, then `throw;` (without the exception instance) is a good way to re-throw the original exception without damaging it, but in your case the entire thing is redundant, so - just lose the `try`/`catch`/`finally` completely and let the `using` worry about the rest. Additionally, might as well keep the query "inline", and using `AsList()` helps make it clear that we're materializing the objects *now* rather than later (which could cause a problem with deferred execution). This is the *same* as the defaults, so the `AsList()` here doesn't change the behavior - just makes it clearer to the reader:

```cs
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
{
    var newslist = (await conn.QueryAsync<News>("select * FROM News")).AsList();
    return Json(new { data = newslist });
}
```

---

In `GetAllData` you aren't using `param`, so trimming - it becomes... huh, the same!

```cs
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.Value))
{
    var newslist = (await connection.QueryAsync<News>("select * FROM News")).AsList();
    return Json(new { data = newslist });
}
```

---

Finally, in the jQuery callback, watch out for XSS - see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47219741/23354) for a very similar example. The problem, to be explicit, is that `response.data[i].newsHeading` could be malicious - for example it could contain `<script>`.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, I will wait for somemore time to see if someone else may point out something else, will mark it correct if you comments are received.

Answer (score 5):

Other minor points:

### Imports

Sort your `using`s, and [move them to the inside of your `namespace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace). Also consider using StyleCop, which would suggest this.

### Underscored privates

Why do these

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly SqlConnectionConfiguration _configuration;
```

have underscores? Typically that's a Python convention. If you're worried about disambiguating them here:

```
    public NewsController(ApplicationDbContext db, SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _db = db;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

then you can simply prefix the destination with `this.`.

### Rethrow

This entire block should be deleted:

```
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

You will still be able to keep your `finally`. However, you shouldn't have your `finally` in there either, because you already have `conn` in a `with`. Your explicit `close` duplicates the `close` that `IDisposable` imposes on that connection.

### Combined declaration

```
    IEnumerable<News> newslist;
    newslist = await connection.QueryAsync<News>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
```

does not need to be two separate statements; you can do the assignment on the first.

Comment: FWIW, the ASP.NET Core team's style guide mentions `_camelCase` for private fields: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/wiki/Engineering-guidelines#coding-style-guidelines--general